# Sunable to upload signed apk on playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload signed apk on playstore but receiving this error
[image]

I have already uploaded one time on playstore now trying to update it. but receiving error

App is developed in ionic +vue

Comment: And what is your question? You signed your apk with a different certificate than the original apk and the new apk is rejected. Sign your apk with your original certificate.

Comment: what is original certificate that is the thing i am not understanding

Comment: you had a key which you used to sign your apk. You need to use this key to sign again

Comment: you mean keystore?

Comment: i have deleted that

Comment: Then you can't update your app anymore in the playstore and need to publish a new app

Comment: but playstore don't allow to delete existing app?

Comment: I guess you can delete your app, as long as you are the owner and have the rights to do so, but this is something you should ask the playstore support